# LongGestureRecogizer issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I have use all gestures in objectiveC.

Now my need is:- 
When we hold UIButton the audio recording is start. And when we release the UIButton the audio recording is stop.

I have use LongGesture like this:-

```
-(void)handLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [record stop];

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];

        [tbl reloadData];
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

        if (player.playing) {
            [player stop];
        }

        if (!record.recording) {
            [self saveMusic];

            AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
            [session setActive:YES error:nil];

            // Start recording
            [record record];
            // [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        } else {

            // Pause recording
            [record pause];
            // [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }        
    }    
}
```

But in this case, when we hold button it is not working. But when we release button the audio starts and stops automatically.(audio is recorded 0.1 second only)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you handling long press gesture on button click ?

Answer (score 0):

Use UIControlEvents instead of Long Gesture.

A system event canceling the current touches for the control.
UIControlEventTouchDown

An event where a finger is dragged just outside the bounds of the control.
UIControlEventTouchUpInside